# Bing Map webpart (Java Script Error)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, google-maps, web-parts, bing-maps

I am trying to convert a SP2007 Map into Sharepoint sandbox soltuion, but for some reason, when i upload my webpart, and try to edit the properties i get this Javascript error,

> The value of the property 'UpdateWebPartMenuFocus' is null or undefined, not a Function object

I did my research on this error, and find just few posts, it comes because If someone didn't referenced Core.js in v4.master (Default Master Page) but I checked and its already referenced as shown below,

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" />
```

and here is my Code,

```
        StringBuilder mapHTML = new StringBuilder();
        mapHTML.Append("<div>");
        mapHTML.Append("<script src=\"https://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3\"></script>");
        mapHTML.Append("<script type='text/javascript' id='clientEventHandlersJS'>");
        mapHTML.Append("var map = null;");
        mapHTML.Append("function GetMap()");
        mapHTML.Append("{");
        mapHTML.Append("try{");
        mapHTML.Append(" var latLon = new VELatLong(52.29504228453734,-2.2851562500000044);");
        mapHTML.Append("map = new VEMap('myMap');");
        mapHTML.Append("map.LoadMap(latLon,5);");
        mapHTML.AppendFormat("map.Find(null, '{0}', null, null, null, null, false, false, false, true,LocFound);", HtmlEncode(_Location));
        mapHTML.Append("}");
        mapHTML.Append("catch(err){}");
        mapHTML.Append("}");
        mapHTML.Append("function LocFound(thelayer, resultsArray, places, hasMore, veErrorMessage)");
        mapHTML.Append("{");
        mapHTML.Append("try{");
        mapHTML.Append("if(places != null && places.length >0)");
        mapHTML.Append("{");
        mapHTML.Append("var latlong = places[0].LatLong;");
        mapHTML.Append("}");
        mapHTML.Append("else");
        mapHTML.Append("{");
        mapHTML.Append("myMap.style.display = 'none';");
        mapHTML.Append("locationError.style.display = 'block';");
        mapHTML.Append("}");
        mapHTML.Append("var shape = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Pushpin,latlong);");
        mapHTML.AppendFormat("shape.SetTitle('{0}');", HtmlEncode(_PushPinTitle));
        mapHTML.Append("map.AddShape(shape);");
        mapHTML.Append("map.SetZoomLevel(14);");
        mapHTML.Append("}");
        mapHTML.Append("catch(err){}");
        mapHTML.Append("}");
        mapHTML.Append("  function addLoadEvent(func) ");
        mapHTML.Append("  { ");
        mapHTML.Append("try{");
        mapHTML.Append("    var oldonload = window.onload; ");
        mapHTML.Append("    if(typeof window.onload != 'function') ");
        mapHTML.Append("    { ");
        mapHTML.Append("      window.onload = func; ");
        mapHTML.Append("    } ");
        mapHTML.Append("    else ");
        mapHTML.Append("    { ");
        mapHTML.Append("      window.onload = function()");
        mapHTML.Append("        { ");
        mapHTML.Append("          func(); ");
        mapHTML.Append("        } ");
        mapHTML.Append("    } ");
        mapHTML.Append("}");
        mapHTML.Append("catch(err){}");
        mapHTML.Append("  } ");
        mapHTML.Append("addLoadEvent(GetMap); ");
        mapHTML.Append("</script>");
        mapHTML.AppendFormat("<div id=\"myMap\" style=\"position:relative\" width:\"{0}\" height:\"{1}\" ></div>", HtmlEncode(_MapWidth), HtmlEncode(_MapHeight));
        mapHTML.AppendFormat("<div id=\"locationError\" style=\"position:relative\">", HtmlEncode(_MapWidth), HtmlEncode(_MapHeight));
        //mapHTML.AppendFormat("{0}", HtmlEncode(_LocationError));
        mapHTML.Append("</br>");
        mapHTML.AppendFormat("{0}", HtmlEncode(_Location));
        mapHTML.Append("</div>");
        mapHTML.Append("</div>");
        Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(mapHTML.ToString()));
        //AddControl(new LiteralControl(mapHTML.ToString()));
```

Now I cant find a way to get rid of this error, Second if anyone knows ***any better way to get a map in a webpart with location name*** like using google API, I seen few projects e.g.

[Bing Map Code Plex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81359/Bing-Maps-in-SharePoint-2010-Web-Part)

But it looks bit old style, and less functionality as there isn't no AJAX controls in it.

(Note: I Can't use silver light, as number of clients are a lot and dont want to force them to install plugins for silver light or any other restrictions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors Disappears when I add this code, it register this script to Sharepoint 2010 script manager and stop conflict, as far as I know, if someone can explain it better then is most welcome.

```
 System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager csm = Page.ClientScript;
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 string SCRIPT_NAME = "MapScript" + this.ID;
    {// all that code above}
 csm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), SCRIPT_NAME, builder.ToString(), false);
```

[Google Map Webpart](http://sp2010googlemaps.codeplex.com/)

This is what I exactly wanted but its Google Maps + its not free for my website (as I charge users for using my sharepoint application)

I was wondering if anyone knows any free licence or way I can use maps as webpart.

Cheers